# list of those Customer IDs from Table X who have bought all of the products from Table Y?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 Tables X & Y,

**Table X**(has 5 records)

```
Cust_Id  Prod_Key 
 1        'A'
 1        'D'
 2        'C'
 3        'D'
 2        'B'
```

**Table Y** (has 2 records)

```
Prod_Key 
  'A'
  'D'
```

Need SQL to list the Cust_ID which has all the products from Table Y.
~ Cannot hard code as the table keeps updated

Comment: have you tried to use joins to get the records?

Comment: Is the combination of Cust_id and Prod_key unique in Table X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
select 
  cust_id 
from 
  Y
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  X 
  on Y.Prod_key = X.Prod_key
Group by 
  Cust_id
having 
 count(DISTINCT X.Prod_key) = (select count(*) from Y);
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/071422/9/0)**

Comment: Thank you Imankur, just trying to understand how "Having" could make a difference.

 Having Count (Distinct X.Prod_Key) = 2 is working, any explanation would help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing using `INNER JOIN` with `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` as below

```
SELECT x.Cust_Id
FROM X x
INNER JOIN Y y ON y.Prod_Key = x.Prod_Key
GROUP BY x.Cust_Id
HAVING COUNT(y.Prod_Key) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Y)
```

Comment: Thanks Susang, this worked .. seems to be much simpler sql than other recommendations.

i am still trying to understand how this Having is working.

Having Count(y.Prod_Key) should return values = 2
Select Count(*) From Y is also 2

If we independently query 
SELECT x.Cust_Id
FROM X x
INNER JOIN Y y ON y.Prod_Key = x.Prod_Key
GROUP BY x.Cust_Id

this would result in 
Cust_Id
1
3

How its finally giving 1 after including Having is the puzzle for me :(

Comment: Exactly `HAVING` is filtering the records. Simply add count columns in your query as `COUNT(y.Prod_Key) countExist` then you get the `countExist` `2` for `x.Cust_Id=1` and `1` for `x.Cust_Id=3` so after adding `HAVING` clause it will return the id which has equal number of `Prod_Key(s)` as we have in the `Y` table. I am sure, you will understand it please try once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to get the unique list of Cust_IDs

`select DISTINCT Cust_Id from X where x.Prod_key in (select y.Prod_key from Y)`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @sunnygud I am not sure why it didn't work. See this [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/071422/13)

Thanks to Ankur Patel for his Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try inner join as you need only the `customerid` whose `productkey` is present in table y

```
SELECT x.Cust_Id 
FROM x 
INNER JOIN y
ON x.Prod_Key = y.Prod_key
```

Comment: This doesnt work, if you see the answer is "1" since only Customer ID : 1 is the only person purchased A, D products in the X table from Y Table.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

select * from x where prod_key in (select prod_key from Y)

Comment: The result is this.

Cust_Id Prod_Key
1 A
1 D
3 D